# FreeRTOS priority and its effect on Thread

Tags: stm32, rtos, freertos, operating-system

I am learning basics of Free RTOS wth a STM32MCU. I defined two threads, each one take mutex, wait for 1000ms and give the mutex again. I have noticed that when the priorities of the threads are not the same, this delay will be different for each thread. This made me wonder because the delay periods are defined the same. Could somebody explain the reason of that? You find a piece of my code here:

```
void StartDefaultTask(void const * argument)
{
  for(;;)
  {
    xSemaphoreTake(Mutex1Handle, portMAX_DELAY);
    LCD1602_setCursor(1, 1);
    LCD1602_print("ThOne1");
    HAL_Delay(1000);
    LCD1602_clear();
    xSemaphoreGive(Mutex1Handle);    
    osDelay(10);
  }
}
void StartTask02(void const * argument)
{
  for(;;)
  {
    xSemaphoreTake(Mutex1Handle, portMAX_DELAY);
    LCD1602_setCursor(2, 1);
    LCD1602_print("ThTwo2");
    HAL_Delay(1000);
    LCD1602_clear();
    xSemaphoreGive(Mutex1Handle);    
    osDelay(10);
  }
```

Comment: What is "HAL_Delay"? You really should be using [`vTaskDelay`](https://www.freertos.org/a00127.html) to perform delays inside tasks because it yields back to the scheduler.

Comment: Do you have any other threads running? Also, mutexes have priority inversion, which means that when a higher priority task wants a mutex, the other task is temporarily running at same higher priority to actually complete what it is doing so the higher priority task does gets the mutex faster.

Comment: @RonBeyer HAL_Delay is a busy loop that waits for the millisecond count from the timer interrupt to count up the given amount. So any task switching may cause jitter to the HAL_Delay.

Comment: @Justme you shouldn't be using busy wait loops in an RTOS. That's what vTaskDelay is designed for.

Comment: @RonBeyer I am not the one using busy loops, the OP is. Forgot to mention that lower priority tasks never get to run unless higher priority tasks sleep.

Comment: @Justme I know, the comment you made sounds like the OP shouldn't want task switching (to avoid issues with the delay) when in fact that's exactly what they should want, just trying to make it clear to the OP. There is a resource contention here that allows the lower priority task block a higher priority one too, which should be avoided if possible.

Comment: @justme Thanks a lot! The problem was using HAL_Delay. Insteas of that I used vTaskDelay. But Could you explain what is the machanism of vTaskDelay?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use HAL_Delay which is an active busy loop of which the RTOS is not aware. vTaskDelay is the RTOS function that suspends the task until enough time has passed.

Comment: Will replacing the mutex with a binary semaphore solve the problem of priority inversion which in mutexes have?

Comment: Huh? It's really the other way around. Mutexes have priority inheritance to solve problems that binary semaphores have.